# salt stack if then else for service

Tags: salt-stack

I have a windows service which I deploy from salt stack. The state looks like this

```
create_executable:
   module.run:
     -  name:  service.create
     -  m_name:  SVC1
     -  bin_path:  d:\svc1.exe
     -  start_type:  auto
```

Now, when I redeploy the service, it says "Exception: Service Already Exists: SVC1". Is there a way to test if the service is running? If the s
ervice is running, I would like to stop it, disable it, delete it and then recreate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [module.wait](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.module.html#salt.states.module.wait) together with a [cmd.run](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.cmd.html#salt.states.cmd.run) that uses the `unless` feature might help in this case.

You need a nice way to check that the service **is not installed** and use this in the unless test. The command itself might something like `echo` - it does not really matter. You can now use `watch` or `watch_in` to make the `module.wait` relying on `cmd.run`.

**untested draft** (note that I don't know windows cli at all):

```
check_if_service_installed:
  cmd.run:
    name: echo 'not installed'
    unless: 'if exists c:\svc1.exe'

create_executable:
  module.wait:
    - name:  service.create
    - m_name:  SVC1
    - bin_path:  d:\svc1.exe
    - start_type:  auto
    - watch:
      - cmd: check_if_service_installed
```

After writing I think that this looks a little complicated for what you try to achieve. Maybe a small batch or powershell script which takes care of being able to be executed again is more straight forward. But this is a matter of taste IMO.

Comment: I was thinking of using Jinja Templates in my state file. Is that a good way to  use them for something like this?

Comment: This approach is used in formulas quite often - should work out of the box. Would be interesting to see your result, if this works. You can usually not access minions data in that case, except of grains data. So a grain might be necessary.

Comment: Yeah, I am having a hard time finding if a service exists on the system. Its hard to distinguish between exist, avaliable and running.

Comment: Is the suggested approach working? If so, may you provide the correct config for the `cmd.run`, that wotks for windows? Might be interesting for future problems... :)